# Misunderstood the 90 day rule and was denied entry

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, denial-of-entry

I planned a trip to Europe earlier but was denied by the French border authorities. I was told that I had already spent 90 days in a 180-day period, and had overstayed by a few days. It was not my intention to do this; I completely misunderstood the definition of the duration of 90 days. I thought I could stay 90 days with every entry.

I was told that my visa is still valid, that I can still enter the EU with the same visa. I have a one-year Schengen multiple-entry visa, valid until December 2017.

Because there is a entry/exit stamp crossed-out, will the border authorities challenge me when they see this 'denied entry' stamp, or will I be allowed to enter as usual?

Comment: You will have to answer about the `denied entry` stamp next time you go. That has been recorded in the database and will be there for all Schengen countries to see.

Comment: You probably want to avoid trying to enter through Germany for example who are notoriously strict with immigration.

Comment: Misunderstood the rules you did? Much confusion in you I sense, yes.

Comment: Don't consider going in trough Sweden or Germany as they are strict about these rules, but they can't deny you because of this

Answer (score 15):

First of all, this is completely your responsibility to make sure you understand and follow the laws.

Regarding your question. If your visa is not cancelled, you may use it later, when 180 days period is over, assuming it is still valid.

But, you will for sure have to explain why France has denied you entrance and it may and almost certainly will make your life more complicated when it comes to obtaining a new visa.